# regarding pthread mutex usage

Tags: pthreads, mutex

```
uint32 abc(int i)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&sharedvar_mutex[i]);

    sharedvar[i][j] = getvalue(i,j);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sharedvar_mutex[i]);
}
```

Is this usage correct?

Will this work as below:
say i can be 1 or 2 and j is a global constant.
thread-A where i=1 calls this function and acquires mutex sharesvar_mutex[1] and modifies 
sharedvar[1][j].
thread-B where i=1 when it enters the function will wait on the mutex.

thread-C where i=2 can enter and acquire mutex sharesvar_mutex[2] and modifies sharedvar[2][j].

Will it work this way?

Thanks!

Comment: It all depends how you declared `sharedvar`. If it's an array of pointers to distinct, separately allocated objects then this is fine. If it's a single array, then you have an object being accessed by one thread while another thread might be modifying it.

Comment: sharedvar is defined as an array -uint32 sharedvar[2][2]; A thread should be able to modify [/read] sharedvar[1][j] when another thread is modifying/reading sharedvar[2][j], but shouldn't be able to read [/modify] sharedvar[1][j].

Comment: That's not technically legal. If you declare `sharedvar` as a single array, then it's a single object. One thread cannot access an object while another thread might be modifying it. You would be okay if you did `uint32* sharedvar[2]; sharedvar[0]=malloc(...);` because then each row would be a separate object. (And `sharedvar` itself would be an object, but you wouldn't modify it after that. So that's okay.) In practice, the code will likely work, but performance will be bad due to [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing).

Comment: @david I disagree 100% with this statement: "If you declare sharedvar as a single array, then it's a single object. One thread cannot access an object while another thread might be modifying it."  It's perfectly safe for one thread to access one element of the array and another thread to access a different element.  Also, 'False sharing' can occur when threads access 2 things on the same cacheline.  It Doesn't matter if they are separate objects.  All you can say is that you might be more likely to get false sharing with an array of uints as compared to some other arrangement.

Comment: @johnnycrash: "It's perfectly safe for one thread to access one element of the array and another thread to access a different element." Really? What if I have `char j[4];` and the platform has *no* single-byte read or write operations?

Comment: @david:  Ok, so with respect to your statement that arrays cannot be accessed safely by multiple threads, I will revise my disagreement from 100% to 99%.  The point about the char array is a good one.

Comment: @johnnycrash: Either it's guaranteed or it's not. The char array example proves it's not. End of story.

Comment: @david: LOL.  I think you miss the point.  People using atomics are interested in performance, not the lowest common denominator.  I think I will stick to assuming that an array of aligned 32 bit values can be safely accessed on many machines.  End of story.

Comment: @johnnycrash: You don't need to assume that. It's a known fact that aligned 32-bit values can be safely accessed on many machines.

Comment: @johnnycrash: I'm just pointing out the errors in what you're saying, as it has been my experience that that kind of reasoning is one of the major causes of buggy, unreliable code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work that way.

One thing you might want to consider.  It looks like you are using the array of mutexes to prevent the getvalue function from being executed at the same time for a given i, and to prevent race conditions when assigning to sharedvar[].  If you wish to prevent getvalue from executing simultaneously for a given i, this is potentially fine.  However, using mutextes just to prevent a race condition when setting an integer in an array is overkill compared to atomic operations.